# how to call php api using asp.net web page using POST method

Tags: php, asp.net, post

i'm beginner ..i have a website whose code is written in php and i need to call that api.php using asp.net ..how can do it...
It has post method which needs to communicate and encode and decode it in JSON and return value

Comment: do you want to call your php from client side (javascript) or from server side (C#) ?

Comment: Add more specific details because REST APIs are language agnostic. You can use function like json_encode/json_decode to send your POST request.

Comment: @ dexion: i need server code from C# ... Let me be clear i have UI designed in asp.net  n trying to login using username and password ..So i need to connect api written in php .. which takes values encodes using JSON and return the value ..So help me out

Comment: i need to hit the api.php and i receive the values in JSON format i.e, username and password and need to compare these values to the value enterned in my UI .if matched then need to navigate to other page..here imp thing is  : 1) To hit the api.php 2) receive the values in JSon compare with the values of UI if successful then navigate to next page

Answer (score 0):

in asp.net, you can call php api by using asp curl function or http method.

For example with this code in the server side:

```
[HttpPost]
public Boolean PostDataToDB(int n, string s)
{
    //validate and write to database
    return false;
}
```

You can use different approches:

**With WebClient:**

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    data["n"] = "42";
    data["s"] = "string value";

    var response = wb.UploadValues("http://www.domain.org/receiver.aspx", "POST", data);
}
```

**With HttpRequest:**

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.domain.org/receiver.aspx");

var postData = "n=42&s=string value";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

**With HttpClient:**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("n", "42"));
    values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("s", "string value"));

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.domain.org/receiver.aspx", content);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

**With WebRequest**

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.domain.org/receiver.aspx");
request.Method = "POST";
string postData = "n=42&s=string value";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close ();

//Response
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

Comment: need to hit the api.php and i receive the values in JSON format i.e, username and password and need to compare these values to the value enterned in my UI .if matched then need to navigate to other page..here imp thing is : 1) To hit the api.php 2) receive the values in JSon compare with the values of UI if successful then navigate to next page